# LINQ - How do I keep my (complex) results ordered?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have LINQ query that is built up in a piecemeal fashion like so:

```
var initialQuery = from item in MyContext where xxx == yyy select item;    
var furtherQuery = from item in initialQuery where bla == foo select new { some stuff };

// more code here...

// eventually:
var yetAnotherQuery = (from item in furtherQuery ...)
                      .OrderBy(my_condition);

// As far as I know, the following query should still maintain the order of the previous one
// see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911942/are-subqueries-in-linqtosql-guaranteed-to-be-in-the-same-order-as-their-parent

var stillAnotherQuery = (from item in yetAnotherQuery
                         select item.data_I_care_about)
                         .Distinct();

// And finally...
var finalQuery = stillAnotherQuery.Skip(PageIndex).Take(PageSize);
```

But I am getting an exception when `Skip()` is called, saying that the query is not ordered!
So apparently what is indicated in my code comment above and the [referenced SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911942/are-subqueries-in-linqtosql-guaranteed-to-be-in-the-same-order-as-their-parent) is not entirely true. In fact [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225481/how-to-check-for-the-presence-of-an-orderby-in-a-objectqueryt-expression-tree/225660#225660) indicates that the preservation of that order is not guaranteed.

Does anyone know a good way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

I considered simply including a `ROW_NUMBER` in my intermediate results, and ordering by that at the very end, but I cannot find a way to get that `ROW_NUMBER` in my results via LINQ.

I have seen several [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365086/how-to-project-a-line-number-into-linq-query-results) SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165028/how-do-i-add-row-number-to-a-linq-query-or-entity) trying to [get the ROW_NUMBER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675222/using-row-number-in-linq-where-clause) in there, but they are all clientside, as far as I have seen.

I seem to have painted myself in a corner.
Anyone know a (LINQ-friendly) way out?

---

### **UPDATE**

---

Some have suggested that I do the `Distinct()` before the `OrderBy()`.
I believe that would give me different results.

Imagine I have this table of data

```
myRank | myData
-------+--------
   3   |    A
   1   |    B
   2   |    A
```

Supposing I am ordering by `myRank`, and the data I care about is `myData`, and imagine my original code was like this:

```
var query = from item in MyTable
            select item;

query = query.OrderBy(item => item.myRank);

var derivedQuery = from item in query        // Note: we throw away myRank
                   select item.myData;

derivedQuery = derivedQuery.Distinct();
```

If I swap the order of the `OrderBy()` and `Distinct()`, I will get different results. I do not want `myRank` to be included in the `Distinct()`.

Sorry, this is part of a much larger process, so it is hard to get all the details into this question.

But hopefully that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that the elements are no longer ordered.

Rather, the problem is that Distinct() returns a `IQueryable<T>` whereas OrderBy() returns `IOrderedQueryable<TSource>`, which is (apparently) required for the paging to work with EF

Swapping the Distinct() and OrderBy() steps should fix things

**Edit**

I suggest something roughly like this:

```
var query = from item in MyTable
        select item;

query = query.GroupBy(item => item.myData, item => item.myRank);
var derivedQuery = query.OrderBy(group => group.Min())
                        .Select(group.Key);
```

Clarifying:

- group by will result in dinstinct keys (myData) anyway
- sorting by the Min() of `myRank` per group will effect the same order as sorting (ascending) by myRank globally first, *then* doing a Distinc()

Comment: I updated the question to indicate why I believe this is not doable in my case.

Comment: LINQ to EF wouldn't work on `I(Ordered)Enumerable<T>`. It's actually `IQuerable<T>` and `IOrderedQueryable<T>`.

Comment: Added a suggestion to address that. Typed on site, untested syntax :)

Comment: Thank you, this seems promising; I will try it out. The crux seems to be that `GroupBy` + `OrderBy` + `Select` can be used to emulate `Distinct` without `Distinct`'s drawback

Comment: This seems to work, I tried it some. I found that `GroupBy` actually preserves the order (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452507/linq-to-objects-does-groupby-preserve-order-of-elements), so I was able to just replace `Distinct` with a `GroupBy` + `Select`, as is a little clearer in DanM's answer.

Comment: As an aside: Holy nested queries, Batman - this makes me yearn for the simplicity of vanilla SQL, type safety be damned!

Comment: @jwd: +1 for that. To me, all that stuff _beyond_ plain LINQ-to-object frequently looks like such a big, whopping [Leaky Abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) it isn't even funny. And, that's ignoring the semantic differences (ever tried predicting your LINQ-to-SQL query performance? Perhaps in 10 years we will have _explain plans_ like all SQL engines do now). <rant status="over" />

Answer (score 2):

Because of its implementation, **[`Distinct` doesn't guarantee that the order is preserved.](http://introducinglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/07/20/use-of-distinct-and-orderby-in-linq.aspx)** You can't run `Skip` on its output because of this, and even if you could, you wouldn't be able to rely on `Skip`'s behavior.

You're going to need to run `OrderBy` *after* you run `Distinct`. I don't see a way to do this with a single call to `OrderBy`, given what you're trying to do. `yetAnotherQuery` and `stillAnotherQuery` have different elements in them, so they're going to need to be sorted separately.

The way I see it, you have two choices. You can either make one trip to the database for `yetAnotherQuery`, then run `Distinct` and `OrderBy` locally for `stillAnotherQuery`:

```
var yetAnotherQuery = (from item in furtherQuery ...)
                      .OrderBy(my_condition);

var stillAnotherQuery = (from item in yetAnotherQuery ...)
                        .Distinct()
                        .OrderBy(my_condition);

var finalQuery = stillAnotherQuery.Skip(PageIndex).Take(PageSize);
```

...or you can make two trips to the database, but do all the sorting and filtering on your database server:

```
var yaq_UnSorted = (from item in furtherQuery ...);

var yetAnotherQuery = yaq_UnSorted
                      .OrderBy(my_condition);

var stillAnotherQuery = (from item in yaq_UnSorted ...)
                        .Distinct()
                        .OrderBy(my_condition);

var finalQuery = stillAnotherQuery.Skip(PageIndex).Take(PageSize);
```

Which solution is best for you will depend on your priorities. The first one will reduce the number of roundtrips to your DB and the amount of data transferred, but it will also use more resources on your app server.

The `Distinct` / `OrderBy` problem is a pretty common snag to run into. Here's a [previous answer of mine on the subject.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962709/ordering-distinct-values-with-linq/6962785#6962785)

Comment: It looks like yetAnotherQuery is completely unused then, yes?

Comment: The problem is that I want the `Distinct()` to act on the result set that does not include the rank. Everything has a unique rank, so the Distinct() would just do nothing if it were included with every row. (See update to my question)

Comment: @jwd - I assumed you had other plans for `yetAnotherQuery`. You're correct, though--in the second code block, `yetAnotherQuery` doesn't affect `finalQuery`, but they both descend from `yaq_UnSorted`. Also, if you don't care about `yetAnotherQuery` by itself, there's no reason to use the first option. I'll check out your edit.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work to put the `OrderBy` method *after* the `Distinct` method?

The problem is that `Distinct` doesn't preserve order.

Reference: http://programminglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/07/20/use-of-distinct-and-orderby-in-linq.aspx

**Update**

Now I see the problem. I think you need to try using `GroupBy` instead of `Distinct`.

Something like this:

```
var query = MyTable
    .OrderBy(item => item.myRank)
    .GroupBy(item => item.myData)
    .Select(grouping => grouping.First().myData);
```

Comment: I updated the question to indicate why I believe this is not doable in my case.

Comment: @jwd, I just updated my answer. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Yes, that is apparently what I need to do. Have an upvote. sehe gets the answer though since he had the key improvement first.

Comment: @jwd, Thanks...and no problem, I saw his update after I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't think the problem is that `Distinct()` changes the order - but it returns a "normal" `IQueryable<T>` instead of a `IOrderedQueryable<T>` which, apparently is required for Linq to Entities `Skip` implementation.

One solution could be reversing the order of the `OrderBy()` and `Distinct()` methods, so that you do the `Distinct()` first, then apply the order later, and then use `Skip()`.

Comment: I updated the question to indicate why I believe this is not doable in my case.